# Working with google calendar api in Django

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

As a start I wanted to view my events from google calendar in Django, I tried the [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python), run successfully, after installing the google-api-python-client and downloading the json file.

I followed the [Google's example page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django), the sample didn't seem to work, I got this error when running `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```
"Must specify either GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, or "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Must specify either GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, or both GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET in settings.py
```

Even after I commented `GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID` and `GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET` from settings.py

**views.py:**

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'client_secret.json')

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
CLIENT_SECRETS,
scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
redirect_uri='http://www.notify-me.ua:8000/complete/google-oauth2/')


@login_required
def home(request):
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()
    if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:
        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                    request.user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        service = build("calendar", "v3", http=http)

        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        eventsResult = service.events()

        return render(request, 'home.html', {
            'eventsResult': eventsResult,
            })

@login_required
def auth_return(request):
    if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, request.REQUEST['state'], request.user):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    storage.put(credential)
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.models import CredentialsField

class CredentialsModel(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    credential = CredentialsField()
```

I want to simply view my events from google calendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the error because there was a line missing in my `settings.py`:

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON = 'client_secret.json'
```

Everything else is in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The related SO question already shows how to print it in the page (by getting the response of the function) and insert to the calendar using **`service.events().insert`**. The document about [Calendars and Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars) can help you understand how to insert, delete, get, patch or update a calendar metadata. [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars) Class provides basic properties and option properties when creating an event.

```
start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
event = service.events().insert(calendarId='<YOUR EMAIL HERE>@gmail.com', body={
'summary': 'Foo',
'description': 'Bar',
'start': {'dateTime': start_datetime.isoformat()},
'end': {'dateTime': (start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()},
}).execute()

print(event)
```

You just have to change `<YOUR EMAIL HERE>` to your gmail account then, it will reflect to your calendar.

Lastly, you might want to check the document about [Handle API Errors](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors), this will be useful on how to handle error responses.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think I am stuck in the configurations of oauth2client, still didn't get to the step you're explaining @Mr.Rebot. I'll make some changes from [docs](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.django_util.html) and see.

Comment: Did you place the client_secret.json in your project?

Comment: If not, place your client_secret.json in your project or specify GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET in settings.py.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the OAuth2 flow to obtain the new credentials .. I have the file ..

Comment: Please take a look at `home` view, I don't want to work with any model because i think this is the origin of the error i get, should I divide the view into 2, to be redirected to the `authorize_url` then save the new credentials without using `Storage()`?

Comment: did you place the client_secret.json same place where your quickstart.py is located, try that and see if the result changes.

Comment: As specified in `CLIENT_SECRETS` variable in view.py, the file is in the parent folder of view.py. The quickstart example worked, am talking about the django project sample.